# Сделать вывод определённых строк из StreamReader

Tags: c#, консоль

В файле на строчках 489 по 499 есть такие строчки текста:

> "Info"
> {
> "Black"
> {
> "ID"        "889871"
> }
> "White"
> {
> "ID"        "998124"
> }
> }

Я пытаюсь вытащить данные, чтобы был такой результат:

```
Info: 
 - name: Black
 - ID: 889871
 
 - name: White
 - ID: 998124
```

Код:

```
using (StreamReader user = new StreamReader(fileInput, true)
{
  while (!user.EndOfStream)
  {
     string line = user.ReadLine();
     // тут что надо написать чтобы вывести?                            
  }
}
```

Comment: Этот текст похож на JSON, но не хватает двоеточий и запятых. Это точный текст вы привели? Какой формат у файла, что за приложение его создаёт?

Comment: Похоже на VDF от Steam, а для него есть уже куча библиотек, например [эта](https://github.com/shravan2x/Gameloop.Vdf).

Answer (score 0):

Решение с использованием Vdf.Net

```cs
using Gameloop.Vdf;

string data = "\"Info\" { \"Black\" { \"ID\" \"889871\" } \"White\" { \"ID\" \"998124\" } }";

dynamic deserializatedData = VdfConvert.Deserialize(data, new VdfSerializerSettings(){UsesEscapeSequences = false});

foreach (var color in deserializatedData.Value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(color.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(color.Value.ID);
}
```